# How to deal with broken images icons?

Tags: php, html

I am getting broken image icon whenever I dynamically display images in a website. What could be the problem?

Here is my inserting button code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['insert_post'])){

    //getting the text data from the fields
    $product_title = $_POST['product_title'];
    $product_cat= $_POST['product_cat'];
    $product_brand = $_POST['product_brand'];
    $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
    $product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
    $product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];

    //getting the image from the field
    $product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
    $product_image_tmp = file_get_contents($_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name']);
    $imagetype=$FILES['product_image']['type'];
    $array=array('jpg','jpeg','png');
    $ext=pathinfo($product_image,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!empty($product_image)){
        if(in_array($ext,$array)){
        }   
        else{
            echo "unsupported format";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "please select the image";
    }

    move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,"product_images/$product_image");

    $insert_product="insert into products (product_cat,product_brands,product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keywords) 
    values('$product_cat','$product_brand ','$product_title','$product_price','$product_desc','$product_image','$product_keywords') ";

    $insert_pro=mysqli_query($conn, $insert_product);

    if($insert_pro){
        echo "<script>alert('product has been inserted!')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('insert_product.php','_self'</script>";
    }
}
```

function page code:

```
function getPro(){
    global $conn;

    $get_pro="select * from products order by RAND() LIMIT 0,6";

    $run_pro=mysqli_query($conn, $get_pro);

    while($row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){
        $pro_id=$row_pro['product_id'];
        $pro_cat=$row_pro['product_cat'];   
        $pro_brand=$row_pro['product_brands'];
        $pro_title=$row_pro['product_title'];  
        $pro_price=$row_pro['product_price'];  
        $pro_image=$row_pro['product_image']; 

        echo "
            <div id='single_product'>
                <h3> $pro_title </h3>
                <img src='adminarea/product_images/$pro_image' width='200';height='200';/>
                 <p><b style='float:right; padding:5px;'> price: ksh $pro_price</b></p>
                 <a href='details.php ?pro_id=$pro_id'style='float:left; padding:5px;'>Details</a>
                 <a href='index.php ?add_cart=$pro_id'><button style='float:right; padding:5px;'>Add to Cart</button></a>
            </div> ";
    }
```

I suspect the problem might be in

```
<img src='adminarea/product_images/$pro_image' width='200';height='200';/>
```

because the images are inserted successfully in database but when I display them on the website page I receive the broken image icon.

Comment: How exactly do you output your image? Where is the code to read them from the database and output them properly?

Comment: `width='200';height='200';` is not valid HTML. Make sure your images exist at the location and that they are readable by your server.

Comment: You may want to use the developer console (F12) and see, what the error is.

Comment: hello NIco I have use  <img src='adminarea/product_images/$pro_image' width='200';height='200';/>  to output images

Comment: Is your image uploaded to the folder you want or not?

Comment: yeah images are uploaded in my folder..

Comment: i have use developers console and the error is [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)sony%20mobile.jpg:1]...How do i solve this?

Comment: thank you all for taking time to consider my problem...i have solved the issue.